# Implementation of hashCode and equals of a custom object to use as a key in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, equals, hashcode

As I know, if we want to use object as key in `HashMap`, we need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods (on that class) to work properly. But in the below code I used object as key but didn't implement above two methods on that `Employee` class, and it's working fine.

Could you please clarify why it's working without `hashCode` and `equals`?

```
public class Employee1 {
    Integer Roll;
    String Name;
    int age;

    Employee1(int roll,String name,int Age)
    {
            this.Roll =roll;
            this.Name= name;
            this.age =Age;
    }
}

public static void main(String ar[]) {
    Map<Employee, Integer> ObjectAsKeyMap = new HashMap<Employee, Integer>();
    Employee e1 = new Employee(10, "Samad", 30);
    Employee e2 = new Employee(50, "Sahar", 20);
    ObjectAsKeyMap.put(e1, 10);
    ObjectAsKeyMap.put(e2, 20);
    if (ObjectAsKeyMap.containsKey(e1))
        System.out.println("this Object is already present in HashMap Value="+ObjectAsKeyMap.get(e1));
}
```

Output:

```
this Object is already present in HashMap Value=10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default implementation of `equals(Object o)` is `this == o`. Since you're using an object as a key, and then using **the same instance** to query the map, it would work.
However, if you had created `Employee e3 = new Employee (10, "Samad", 30)`, even though logically it should be equal to `e1`, it would not have worked, since you did not implement `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` as required.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is not that you must override both `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Rule is that, if you override one, you must override the other. Also, make sure the key is *immutable*, else you won't find the key if it is modified after being added to the map.

Also an important point is that, you should use the same fields to calculate the `hashCode` that you're using in `equals()`.

The default implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Object` class already satisfies the contract of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Object's default `equals` method returns `true` (and the same `hashCode`) if it's the same object reference, and you didn't override them in `Employee`.  You are supplying the same object reference, `e1`, as what's already in the `HashMap`, so it `containsKey(e1)` returns `true`.  If you were to create a separate `Employee` object, `e3`, with the same attributes as `e1`, then `containsKey(e3)` would return `false` unless you override `equals` and `hashCode` properly in `Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Object` already contains implementations for `hashCode` and `equals`, and these work fine in a `HashMap`. The behavior that you'll get, however, is comparing for the *same object*, not whether two different objects are equivalent.

The important rule is that if you *do* override `equals`, you need to override `hashCode` so that objects that are "equal" have the same `hashCode` (which means that the `equals` method needs to compare all of the fields that `hashCode` uses to build its value).